# Equivariant cohomology of grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

The Grassmannian $X=Gr(2,\mathbb C^4)$ has an involution $\sigma:V \mapsto V^{\perp}$ with respect to the symplectic form $antidiag(1,1,-1,-1)$. The torus equivariant cohomology of the grassmannian over $\mathbb Z$ is well known and as a module it is generated by the Schubert classes over the base ring $\mathbb Z[t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4]$. Not all the Schubert classes are invariant under $\sigma$, for example the class $\tau_{2}$ goes to $\tau_{1,1}$ and vice versa. Then what could be a basis for the module $H_{<\sigma>}^*(X)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$ ?